# What is the most elegant way to limit /tmp?

Tags: disk-usage, tmp

Recently I was [struck by this tricky bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543906/why-does-e-cryptfs-keep-filling-up-tmp). In it, `/tmp` gets overflowed with symlinks until the system runs out of inodes. What is the best way to be sure that this can never happen again?

I'd like to,

- Limit the size of tmp so I don't have to worry about a cache monopolizing the whole drive.
- Limit the amount of files in tmp I can continue to create new files for important stuff.

Comment: Related/duplicate question on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/a/619398/238103

Comment: No great solutions, but: 1) use tmpwatch to delete unused symlinks, 2) increase number of inodes on your filesystem

Comment: What type of filesystem is your /tmp, currently? tmpfs? ext3? btrfs? A separate filesystem or part of /?

Comment: Were all these symlinks created by a process running as root?

Comment: _monitizing_? Do you mean _monopolizing_?

Comment: How do you `mount` `/tmp` - is it a `tmpfs`? If it is a `tmpfs` then it *already is* limited. If it is *not* then, depending on your filesystem, you can `mount` it with options that will limit it. Also if it is *not* a `tmpfs` then *why not*? You should easily be able to spare at least a few hundred mbs of RAM for such an application on any Linux system running on any computer manufactured within the last half-decade or so, and that's before you compress it with `zram`.